# Open containing folder and select file, not select it

Tags: c#, process

In my source code, I create a folder and save files inside it.

I'm trying to create an "Open containing folder" button, that opens the folder of a file, and select this file.

```
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    string args = string.Format("/e, /select, \"{0}\"", filePath);
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.FileName = "explorer";
    info.Arguments = args;
    Process.Start(info);
}
```

Everytime I try to open a folder with this code in the very fist time, the folder opens, but the file isn't selected (I want the file to be selected).

If I close this folder and click on this button again, the folder will open again, but this time the file will be selected as it should be.

What do you think about it? What could affect it?

---

**Edit:**

1. I debugged it, and I pass the correct file paths, and the files are existing in the folder (if they would not exists, I wouldn't getting into the `if`)
2. It is happening one time for each folder. If I open in the past this folder by this button, it will continue to open the folder and to select the file

---

I don't know if it necessary but I'm using Windows7, Visual Studio 2015, .NET Framework 4.6.2.

Comment: What's the value of "filePath" when first clicking the button?

Comment: Your code seems fine. I suggest you to set a breakpoint and grab value of `args`. Then go to command line and start explorer with same parameters. Check if you can do it manually

Comment: Tried your code: I cannot reproduce your behavior. For me, the file is selected every time. Maybe the value of your filePath is not right the 1st time you call it? (Tested on Windows 10)

Comment: @ThomasD.I debug it, the filepath is right, and the files exists

Comment: I'm not sure if this can cause the problem but I would suggest you use `info.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);` to set the start position (working folder).

Comment: @Idoroni Could it be, that the button press sets the focus to the actual button and overrites the selecition of the explorer before it gets executed or so? The 2nd time the button is pressed, it is already selected and maybe doesn't override the explorer selection? .... I know, it's a long shot ;)
Try to select the button beforehand with Tabulator, and then press it.

Comment: @Julo I tried it, but it not change my problem

Comment: @ThomasD. I try to debug it, and it call to my function only 1 time every click

Comment: @Idoroni Yes, what i meant is that you should navigate to your button with the tabulator-key and then press the space-key, instead of the mouse-click.

Comment: @ThomasD.thanks for your answers. not change the problem too

Comment: @ldoroni The code you posted works fine *(even without `WorkingDirectory` update)* on Win7Pro, VS2015 Express, and I even installed the .NET Framework 4.6.2. I tested "open files" in different directories. I used absolute and relative path. Every time it was a success. Function failed only when the path was written as: `filePath = "../2.txt"` - `File.Exists == true`, explorer open result: different directory, no file selected. `filePath = @"..\2.txt"` == OK. Try to check the application on a different PC, and/or different *(simple)* project. Test also path separator type and MAXPATH length.